# How faithful are the Miss Kobayashi's Dragon Maid season 1 and 2 anime to the manga source material?

Tags: miss-kobayashis-dragon-maid

I'm thinking of picking up Miss Kobayashi's Dragon Maid and am wondering about any significant differences between the source material manga, and the anime (both season 1 and 2).